# How to serve a music stream (e.g. internet radio) via Kodi's music library?

Tags: kodi

How to serve music streams from internet radios via Kodi's music library and add metadata to it?

What I've tryed so far is to put the stream url in a `.strm` file:

```
# cat br-klassik.strm
http://br-brklassik-live.cast.addradio.de/br/brklassik/live/mp3/128/stream.mp3
```

The docs tell to add a `album.nfo` or a `artist.nfo` but I don't know how to connect the stream information with those informations.

```xml
# cat br-klassik.nfo
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<album>
  <title>BR-Klassik</title>
  <genre clear=true>Internetradio</genre>
  <track>
    <position>Track Number (1)</position>
    <title>br-klassik</title>
  </track>
</album>
```

Is there a `song.nfo` file similar to `musicvideo.nfo`

I'd expect something like this:

```xml
# cat br-klassik.nfo
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<song>
  <title>BR-Klassik</title>
  <genre clear=true>Internetradio</genre>
</song>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no song.nfo, you could just load it via file mode, but then you have no stream infos.

Have you checked if the stream is available via an existing plugin?
Like https://kodi.tv/addon/music-add-ons-plugins/shoutcast-2 or https://kodi.tv/addon/music-add-ons-plugins/radio